# Can GLSL perform a recursion formula calculation? Or how can I speed up this formular

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, opengl-es, glsl

I want to implement this formula in my iOS App. Is there any way to using GLSL to speed this formula up. Or can I use mental or something to speed this formula up?

```
for (k = 0; k < imageSize; k++) {
    imageOut[k] = imageOut[k-1] * a + imageIn[k] * b;
}
```

OpenCL is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there, as Dietrich Epp already pointed out, is a IIR filter. Now on a computer there's no such thing as "inifinite", you're always limited by number precision, memory, available computational time etc. – even if you executed that loop ad infinitum, due to the limited precision of your typical number representation you'll loose anything meaningful to roundoff errors quite early on.

So lets be honest about it and call a FIR filter with a very long response time. Can those be parallelized? Yes, they can, but for that we have to leave the time domain and look at it from the frequency domain.

Assume you can model the response to a system (=filter) to all the possible signals there are, then "playing back" that response based on the signal gives you the desired output. In the frequency domain that would be a "recording" of the system in response to a broadband signal covering all the frequencies. But that signal is just a simple impulse. That's where the terms FIR and IIR get their middle *I* from.

Any applying the impulse response of the system to an arbitrary signal by means of a *convolution* gives you what the system would respond to like to the signal itself. However calculating a convolution in the time domain is the same as multiplying the Fourier transform of the signal with the Fourier transform of the impulse response and transforming the result back, i.e.

```
s * r = F^-1(F(s) · F(r))
```

And Fourier transforms are one of the things that can be well parallelized and GPUs are really quite good at doing.

Now there are GLSL based Fourier transform codes, but normally these are written in OpenCL or CUDA to run on GPUs.

Anyway, here's the recipe for you:

Determine the cutoff `k` for which your IIR becomes indistinguishable from a FIR. Determine the Fourier transform of the impulse response (= complex spectral response, CSR). Fourier transform the signal (=image) multiply with the CSR and transform back.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic IIR filter, and the data dependencies cause problems when converting it to SIMD code.  This means that you can't do the operation as a simple transform feedback or render-to-texture operation.  In other words, the GPU is designed to work on a bunch of data in parallel, but your formula forces the output to be computed serially (you can't compute `out[k]` without computing `out[k-1]` first).

I see two ways to optimize this:

- You can use SIMD on the CPU.  For iOS, this means ARM NEON.  See articles like [Optimising IIR Filters Using ARM NEON](http://dspace.mah.se/bitstream/handle/2043/13691/exarbete%20Sebastian%20Holgersson%202012-04-25.pdf?sequence=2) or [Parallelization of IIR Filters using SIMD Extensions](http://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~rkutil/publication/Kutil08b.pdf).
- You can redesign the filter as an FIR filter, completely eliminating data dependencies.

Unfortunately, there is no easy translation to GLSL.  Maybe you could use Metal instead of NEON, I'm not sure.